# Huawei E3372h-320 hilink USSD /api/ussd/get and /api/ussd/send errors

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, ussd

I'm trying to get the USSD send and go to work but is getting errors as below. ussd/send (error 111016) and ussd/get (125003). Can you kindly please advise where I might be going wrong?

**Script**

```
#!/bin/sh

MODEM_IP="192.168.8.1"

if [ -e /usr/bin/xml_pp ]; then
 pprint="/usr/bin/xml_pp";
else
 pprint="/usr/bin/tee";
fi

curl -s -X GET "http://$MODEM_IP/api/webserver/SesTokInfo" > ses_tok.xml

COOKIE=`grep "SesInfo" ses_tok.xml | cut -b 58-185`
TOKEN=`grep "TokInfo" ses_tok.xml | cut -b 205-236`

send_ussd()
{
curl \
    -X POST "http://$MODEM_IP/api/ussd/send" \
    -H "Cookie:$COOKIE" \
    -H "__RequestVerificationToken:$TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" \
    -d "<Request><Content>*136#</Content><CodeType>CodeType</CodeType></Request>"| $pprint;
}

get_ussd()
{
    curl \
    -X POST "http://$MODEM_IP/api/ussd/get" \
    -H "Cookie: $COOKIE" \
    -H "__RequestVerificationToken: $TOKEN" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" \
    -d "<request><content>*136#</content><codeType>CodeType</codeType></request>"|$pprint;
}

send_ussd
sleep 10
get_ussd
```

**Results**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Projects/$ ./token.sh
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   173  100   101  100    72   1553   1107 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2661



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
<code>111016</code>
<message></message>
</error>



  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   160  100    88  100    72   1466   1200 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  2711

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<error>
<code>125003</code>
<message/>
</error>
```

When running the USSD on the `http://192.168.8.1/html/content.html#ussd` web interface I get:

```
send:*136#
Received:Airtime:R0.00 Data:347.92 MB Minutes:60:00 1. XtraTime 2. Buy with Bank Card 3. Buy with YelloBucks 4. Buy with Airtime 0. More
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't fully read through the error codes but this should get you the help you need

```
[Github repo](https://github.com/if0xx/Huawei-Hilink-API/blob/master/README.md)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).